# Flutter : Just Audio "No Network Security Config specified, using platform default"

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player, just-audio

I am using [just audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) Package when I try to play audio i face this error **No Network Security Config specified, using platform default**. i was check with multiple url also my all url have **https**.

But when I tried with audioplayers package it worked. I don't know why I was facing this error.

first i was create object same as below.

```
final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
```

and then i was create one simple function and call that function button click.

```
    Future<void> play() async {
    try {
      audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
          "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3"
        )));
      audioPlayer.play();
      // await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(url));
    } catch (e) {
      print("Here : $e");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you implying that the error is printed with "Here : "? If so, I find the example a bit suspect since it doesn't use `await`. It is not possible for that code block to throw that exception in that try block. Also, doesn't the official example in just_audio/example successfully demonstrate your use case working?